# setting slickgrid columns' width automatically

Tags: javascript, css, slickgrid

I'm working with slickgrid, I want to know is there any way to adjust slickgrid columns' width automatically? I'm setting width manually in every column like

```
{id: "title", name: "Title", field: "title", width: 120, cssClass: "cell-title", sortable: true, editor: Slick.Editors.Text}
```

I want slickgrid to auto increase/decrease column width according to the high/low resolutions for different screens.

Comment: You can try the `forceFitColumns` options parameter.